# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/http/message/BasicNameValuePair

Tags: java, maven, java-ee-8

I make servlet java project and I need to call bitrix's rest api (Actually, it doesn't mater). I made next method:

```
public Credentials loadAuthToken(String client_id, String client_secret, String code) throws BitrixApiException {
        BitrixClientImpl bitrixClient = new BitrixClientImpl(bitrixHttpClient, credentials);
        final List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<>();
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("client_id", client_id));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("client_secret", client_secret));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("code", code));
        String result = bitrixClient.executeOAuth(client_id, client_secret, code);

        GsonBuilder builder = new GsonBuilder();
        Gson gson = builder.create();
        credentials = gson.fromJson(result, AuthCredentials.class);
        return credentials;
    }
```

On the first line, that's contain creating new `BasicNameValuePair`'s object I have next error:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/http/message/BasicNameValuePair
    ru.hack.project.api.bitrix.BitrixPlatform.loadAuthToken(BitrixPlatform.java:67)
    ru.hack.project.platform.commands.GetCodeCommand.execute(GetCodeCommand.java:32)
    ru.hack.project.platform.controllers.FrontController.doGet(FrontController.java:26)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
Root Cause
```

What could be reason? Thanks.

Update:
pom.xml

```
<project
        xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>ru.bitrix.proj</groupId>
    <artifactId>bitrix-proj</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <lombok.version>1.18.10</lombok.version>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.13</source>
                    <target>1.13</target>
                    <encoding>UTF8</encoding>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>LATEST</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>attach-sources</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>jar</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>attach-test-sources</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>test-jar</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>fluent-hc</artifactId>
            <version>4.5.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>4.5.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>20140107</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-beanutils</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-beanutils</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>${lombok.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>6.9.6</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.6</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

I run my project by Tomcat

Comment: Are you including your dependencies in your final jar , aka are you using a fat jar?

Comment: Where is it includes?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking/ I don't understand you're comment. Could you post your pom as well as how you run your project?

Comment: I've added pom.

Comment: @PiRocks, Have you ideas about this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I forgot to add all elements to the output layout in the artifacts of the project settings.